# Trying to extract repeating pattern from string in php/javascript

Tags: regex

The following is in PHP but the regex will also be used in javascript.

Trying to extract repeating patterns from a string

string can be any of the following:

```
"something arbitrary"
"D123"
"D111|something"
"D197|what.org|when.net"
"D297|who.197d234.whatever|when.net|some other arbitrary string"
```

I'm currently using the following regex: `/^D([0-9]{3})(?:\|([^\|]+))*/`

This correctly does not match the first string, matches the second and third correctly. The problem is the third and fourth only match the Dxxx and the last string.  I need each of the strings between the '|' to be matched.

I'm hoping to use a regex as it makes it a single step. I realize I could just detect the leading Dxxx then use explode or split as appropriate to break the strings out. I've just gotten stuck on wanting a single regular expression match step.

This same regex may be used in Python as well so just want a generic regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a dynamic number of capture groups in a regular expression, but if you know some upper limit to how many parts you would have in one string, you can just repeat the pattern that many times:

```
/^D([0-9]{3})(?:$|\|)(.*?)(?:$|\|)(.*?)(?:$|\|)(.*?)(?:$|\|)(.*?)(?:$|\|)/
```

So after the initial `^D([0-9]{3})(?:$|\|)` you just repeat `(.*?)(?:$|\|)` as many times as you need it.

When the string has fewer elements, those remaining capture groups will match the empty string.

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/jL2oX6/1).

Answer (score 0):

Is something like `preg_match_all()` (the PHP variant of a global match) also acceptable for you?

Then you could use:

```
^(?|D([0-9]{3})|^.+$|(?!^)\|([^|\n]*)(?=\||$))
```

This will match everything in a string in different matches, e.g. take your string:

```
D197|what.org|when.net
```

It will you then give three matches:

```
D197
what.org
when.net
```

Running live: https://regex101.com/r/jL2oX6/4 (Everything in green are your *group* matches. Ignore what's in blue.)